# How to manage getCookie function and Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics

I'm actually working on a data analysis project and I found these lines inside the HTML code of the website :

```
function getCookie(cname) {
      var name = cname + "=";
      var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
      for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
          var c = ca[i];
          while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
          if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
      }
      return "";
  }

  if (getCookie('cookiebar') == 'true')
  {
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
      ga('send', 'pageview');
  }
```

I'm not familiar with JavaScript so I will truly appreciate your kind explanation about the purpose of the code after "if (getCookie('cookiebar') == 'true')". Below is what I understand :

First, we create a function which will research the name of a cookie which corresponds to "cname" parameter.

In the second part of the code, we will try to find if 'cookiebar' exists.

If 'cookiebar' does not exist that is because the user doesn't accept cookies and Analytics script is not launched. If it does, Analytics script is launched.

But could anybody please tell me if the script is launched even if the user ignore the message (i.e does not accept nor refuse) ?

Comment: It sounds like you have separate code that prompts visitor to accept and I assume sets a cookie if they do.  So, what happens if they ignore the message? You will need to post that code in order for us to determine

Comment: if `getCookie('cookiebar')` is false, then a Google Analytics instance will not be created. Some other piece of code (I.e. asking the user if it is OK to store cookies) is what dictates the `cookiebar` cookie.

Answer (score 0):

The script will not run if the user ignores the message.